# How to get the save Event in ckeditor editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

How  to get the save event in ckeditor so I can make ajax call to save the data.

Here I upload image
[image]

Comment: Check the [Getting and Saving Data](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata) documentation and the SDK samples: [Saving Data in CKEditor Replacing a Textarea](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/savetextarea.html) and [CKEditor in Ajax Applications](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/saveajax.html).

Answer (score 1):

.formSubmit is class name of form,

var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData(); this is data of textarea

```
 $('.formSubmit').submit( function(){
 var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ck_bienban_1_luu.php',// url of phpcode save
      data: {
           data: data,
       },
         success: function() {
           },
       });
return(false);

}
);
```